# Need customization for selection of Shipping method on product level on CHECKOUT page

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, shipping-methods, multishipping

We need some customization for the selection of the `Shipping method` **based on the product level** on the `Checkout page`.

For example:

I have 3 products in the cart and move forward with place order will land us on checkout page and there, the Shipping method block in which it will show me 3 products. Each product will show Shipping method. For example :standard  delivery ( x cost set from magento admin ) and express delivery ( x cost set from magento admin )

I.E :
Checkout page

Shipping method :

> Product 1 Standard delivery ( x cost ) Express delivery ( y cost )
>
> Product 2 Standard delivery (x cost ) Expresss delivery ( y cost )
>
> Product 3 Standard delivery (x cost ) Expresss delivery ( y cost )

Anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think there is such possibility to show shipping cost for each product. Its possible that you can define shipping according for each product but if there are 3 product then it will not display as 3 shipping. Here are few free extension that make shipping easy. Check if these can help you. [1] http://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html [2] http://webshopapps.com/uk/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/product-flat-rate-shipping-extension.html

Comment: You can assign shipping rate as per product & make sum of that all rate and make final shipping rate for that shipping method.